# Regex pattern validation for variable number of number pairs

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to verify that a string is in the correct format...

- Number pairs, seperated by a hyphen, each number with a max of 3 digits
- No negative numbers
- Pairs are seperated by a `|`

Pattern:

```
XXX-XXX
XXX-XXX|XXX-XXX|...
```

Example valid input:

```
var string1 = "18-200";         // Single entry
var string2 = "18-200|36-90";   // Multiple entries
```

Example invalid input:

```
var string3 = "18-2000";        // Failed because the second number has 4 digits
var string4 = "1-1-1-1";        // Failed because there are 4 alternatives, not 2
var string5 = "-20-100";        // Failed because it starts with a negative
```

I've come up with the following pattern:

```
^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+$
```

But the expression doesn't match all of the criteria, for example `1-1-1-1` is still okay.

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: How do you actually store your data? (e.g. `var data = "12-15";` _or_ `var data = "random text 12-11";`)

Comment: @Steven 18-45|80-100 like this if single value means 18-45

Comment: @stevan min and max number digits is 3 only

Comment: What should happen in the event the data is `1-1-1-1`?

Comment: it should not allow...actually i need regex to match min age-max age for multiple values it should be min age-max age|min age-max age|min age-max age

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach (for each number up to 3 digits):

```
^[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}(?:\|[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3})*$
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/PLLi4X/1). Essentially, you just repeat the first part of the pattern, preceding it with escaped `|`, then (with `*`) make sure the whole group is repeated - or not.

Escaping is important, as `|` is a metacharacter. And when you use this string in Angular Validator *(as it somehow turned out)*, you should escape the escaping character (`\`) in your string literal, so it becomes...

```
requiredPattern: "^[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}(?:\\|[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3})*$"
```

Comment: this is not working, i need min and max numbers is 2 digits only and also it shows error when patter gave like this 11-11|11-11|11-23

Comment: syntax error came--ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[0-9]{1,3}+-[0-9]{1,3}+(?:|[0-9]{1,3}+-[0-9]{1,3}+)*$/: Nothing to repeat
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>

Comment: Syntax error came out of what? Once again: have you checked the demo? Why have you dropped the escaping character in `(?:\| ...`?

Comment: its working in demo but when i use inside my angular validator it throws error but the previous one of yours working fine no syntax error for that regex

Comment: Look, no offence, but your question is a rabbit hole: each time the answer is given, it turns out there's a very important detail that you somehow missed. Not only it's a bit annoying trying to help someone who doesn't seem to care about being helped, but also this makes the question more and more specific - and less and less useful to any other SO users.

Comment: i don't think so i clearly mentioned sorry for u to not understand it

Comment: Could you point me to the exact place in your question mentioning Angular?

Comment: @raina77ow yes, I assumed they were just hangovers. And, of course, the old pattern does work with them in place in other implementations! (like your linked example)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- You always match from the `start` of the supplied string to the `end`
- You always match in pairs like `XXX-XXX`
- Multiple pairs are separated by `|`

Then we could write a simplified regex...

```
^\d-\d(\|\d-\d)*$
```

Which we can then expand to arrive at...

```
^\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}(?:\|\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})*$
^                                        : Start of string
 \d{1,3}                                 : Match a number 1 to 3 times
        -                                : Match literally
         \d{1,3}                         : Match a number 1 to 3 times
                (?:                      : Start of non-capturing group
                   \|                    : Match literally
                     \d{1,3}             : Match a number 1 to 3 times
                            -            : Match literally
                             \d{1,3}     : Match a number 1 to 3 times
                                    )    : End of group
                                     *   : Quantifier for 0 or more occurrences of the non-capturing group
                                      $  : End of string
```

Which we can then test in JS using match to verify...

```
var regex  = /^\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}(?:\|\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})*$/;
var testStrings = [
    `1-12`,
    `1-12|88-100`,
    `1-12|88-100|1-111`,
    `1-1-1-1`,
    `1-12|`,
    `1-12|1-1-2`,
];

for (let num in testStrings) {
    console.log(testStrings[num].match(regex));
}
```

Output, as expected:

```
["1-12", index: 0, input: "1-12", groups: undefined]
["1-12|88-100", index: 0, input: "1-12|88-100", groups: undefined]
["1-12|88-100|1-111", index: 0, input: "1-12|88-100|1-111", groups: undefined]
null
null
null
```